# Jupyter, AttributeError: type object 'Widget' has no attribute 'observe'

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I tried to use observe for my toggleButton

```
wtarget = widgets.ToggleButtons(
    description='select target',
    options=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
wtarget.observe(target_on_value_change, names='value')
```

It displayed this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ToggleButtons' object has no attribute 'observe'
```

I had no problem with another MacBook but this one showed the problem. 
I am using MacBook, 10.12. Python Version 4.0.0. ipywidgets was installed via pip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggests that you have an old version of traitlets. `.observe` was added in traitlets 4.1:

```
pip install --upgrade traitlets
```

You may want to upgrade more than that:

```
pip install --upgrade ipywidgets
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also arise if you inherit from a widget but forget to call super. That is

```py
from ipywidgets import VBox, Text

class MyToggle(VBox):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [Text(description="hello")]

my_toggle = MyToggle()
my_toggle
```

returns

```
# ...
# AttributeError: 'MyToggle' object has no attribute '_model_id'
```

The solution is to call super in `__init__`:

```
class MyToggle(VBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyToggle, self).__init__()
        self.children = [Text(description="hello")]
```